# Bug in the circle menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

menu itself: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxXvoG

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').hover(function() {
        $("ul li").eq($(this).index()).trigger("mouseover");
    }, function() {
        $("ul li").eq($(this).index()).trigger("mouseout");
    });
    $('li').hover(function() {
        $('a').eq($(this).index()).css('background-color', '#333333');
        $(this).css('background-color', '#333333');
    }, function() {
        $('a').eq($(this).index()).css('background-color', '#666666');
        $(this).css('background-color', '#666666');
    });
});
$( "a" )
  .on( "mouseenter", function() {
    $( this ).css({
      "color": "#00CAF2"
    });
  })
  .on( "mouseleave", function() {
    var styles = {
      "color":""
    };
    $( this ).css( styles );
  });
```

The problem: when you hover a link, block selected normally, but when you move cursor from menu item title to its block, somewhy block "ssssssss8"(first block in 'ul' list) selects too.

Comment: why are you triggering `mouseover` and `mouseout`? I removed those triggers and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Yes, but when you hover a link, selection of the block disappears. So it's not working properly right now.

Comment: @BigDaddy: The biggest problem is that you're triggering `mouseover` and `mouseout`. That will not be part of your solution, and is causing a whole new set of problems, so remove it.

Comment: @Andrew Coonce: And what to use instead?

Comment: @BigDaddy: To be honest, I don't know. If I did, I'd post an answers for you...but I do know that falsifying mouse events is not the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add classes for links:

```
<a class="link" href="#menu" id=a1>ssssssss1</a>
<a class="link" href="#menu" id=a2>ssssssss2</a>
<a class="link" href="#menu" id=a3>ssssssss3</a>
<a class="link" href="#menu" id=a4>ssssssss4</a>
<a class="link" href="#menu" id=a5>ssssssss5</a>
<a class="link" href="#menu" id=a6>ssssssss6</a>
<a class="link" href="#menu" id=a7>ssssssss7</a>
<a class="link" href="#menu" id=a8>ssssssss8</a>
```

then modify jquery selector a little bit (added .link):

```
    $('a.link').hover(function() {
        $("ul li").eq($(this).index()).trigger("mouseover");
    }, function() {
        $("ul li").eq($(this).index()).trigger("mouseout");
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, now it's almost working. Except ssssssss8, when you hover this link, selection of the block disappears. Problem only on this block, all others works properly after your fix.

Comment: looks like it's a bug into html structure (I mean this one with "ssssssss8".

Answer (score 1):

Removed the $('a').hover function and the 'ssssssss8' is not blocking anymore. See the commented code below,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //$('a').hover(function() {
            //$("ul li").eq($(this).index()).trigger("mouseover");
        //}, function() {
            //$("ul li").eq($(this).index()).trigger("mouseout");
        //});

        $('li').hover(function() {
            $('a').eq($(this).index()).css('background-color', '#333333');
            $(this).css('background-color', '#333333');
        }, function() {
            $('a').eq($(this).index()).css('background-color', '#666666');
            $(this).css('background-color', '#666666');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Not exactly what I want, because when you hover a link, selection of the block disappears.